# How to run a local daemon with GUI?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon, solo-mining

I downloaded 0.10.3.1 GUI, made a new wallet and just finished synchronizing. I went to start solo mining and am getting an error message saying that it, "Couldn't start mining. Mining is only available on local daemons. Run a local daemon to be able to mine (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0pIr.png)".

I am super new to all of this, but couldn't find the answer searching around so any advice setting this up would be super helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you get this error, then you probably altered the default daemon settings to point to a different daemon. If you did not, then this appears to be a bug. If you did, then you need to undo those changes. Then, starting the GUI will ask you whether to start the daemon, and you can then accept. After some time spent  syncing the blockchain, you will then be able to start mining.

Note that solo mining in this way, while you get an equivalent long term expected gain, means you get a LOT of time with nothing, and get a whole block reward very infrequently. It does however help the network more than pool mining.

If you've not yet synced a local daemon, I recommend upgrading to the latest version (0.11.0.0), which has substantial improvement on the sync time and download size. Replacing your binaries with the updated ones is the only thing that's needed to upgrade.

Comment: My daemon address is pointed to node.moneroworld.com:18089. What should it be?

Comment: If you want a local daemon, set it to "localhost" and "18081". I think having both empty also works, but not 100% sure.